# Python polar plot: Plot values corresponding to the angle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot sensor data, which was recorded with different angles.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 #create dataframe, each row contains an angle and a corresponding value
 df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["angle","value"])
 df.angle = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60]
 df['value'] = df.apply(lambda row: 100 -row.angle/2 , axis=1)
 print(df)

 #plotting
 plt.polar(df['angle'].values,df['value'].values)
 plt.show()
```

This returns:

[image]

But I need a plot that shows a value of 100 at zero degrees, 97.5 at 5 degrees and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`theta` in `plt.polar(theta, r)` needs to be in radians. You can make a new column converting the angle to radians using the following:

```
import math
df['rad'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.angle*math.pi/180, axis=1)
plt.polar(df['rad'], df['value'])
```

This results in this plot:.

[image: This plot]